# WebSharper error when building under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, f#, msbuild, xbuild, websharper

I'm trying to build a project using WebSharper under Mac OSX and I got the following error :

```
Target WebSharperCompile:
        Compiling with WebSharper..
/Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/packages/WebSharper.2.5.125.62/build/WebSharper.targets: error : Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: srcOffset  at System.Buffer.BlockCopy (System.Array src, Int32 srcOffset, System.Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.PE.Image.GetDebugHeader (System.Byte[]& header) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetDebugHeader (System.Byte[]& header) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols (ISymbolReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Compiler.Loader.load (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 flp, System.Byte[] bytes, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 symbols, IntelliFactory.Core.AssemblyResolver aR) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Compiler.Loader.LoadFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    Task "WebSharperTask" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "WebSharperCompile" in project "/Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/RegionsInfo/RegionsInfo.fsproj".-- FAILED
Done building project "/Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/RegionsInfo/RegionsInfo.fsproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/RegionsInfo/RegionsInfo.fsproj (default targets) ->
/Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/packages/WebSharper.2.5.125.62/build/WebSharper.targets (WebSharperCompile target) ->

    /Volumes/Data/Dev/Landmark_tools/packages/WebSharper.2.5.125.62/build/WebSharper.targets: error : Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: srcOffset  at System.Buffer.BlockCopy (System.Array src, Int32 srcOffset, System.Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.PE.Image.GetDebugHeader (System.Byte[]& header) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetDebugHeader (System.Byte[]& header) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols (ISymbolReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Compiler.Loader.load (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 flp, System.Byte[] bytes, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1 symbols, IntelliFactory.Core.AssemblyResolver aR) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Compiler.Loader.LoadFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

     0 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)
```

I can build the same project under Windows without any problems.
Under windows I can simply do `msbuild` or specify a configuration `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release` or even the Fake compiler.
And under Mac OSX whatever I try to use (using xbuild or Fake)  I always got the same error. Last time I had that I was able to build the project using Release mode but here it's not working either.

I have hosted the project under github : https://github.com/MangelMaxime/BugReport

I know it's not recommended but better to have the same conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Cecil bug that was recently fixed: ["Non-negative number required" trying to read f# dll](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/174)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I will try it this evening.

Comment: I still have the same error. I try to change Cecil downloaded from NuGet change the ones used by WebSharper. Nothing change... Just saw that Cecil on nugget date of 2012. Will try to find somewhere else.

Comment: Really strange I build a project using the same NuGet than the last one and it's compile...